# Typescript - loop inside a array of async functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous

in nodejs/nest =>
i have an object of functions defined by keys.
But when i loop those functions, the async behavior is broken.
Any idea why functions called from `serializationByService` doesnt have the same behavior ?

```
const keys = [key1, key2]
const serializationByService: Record<string, Promise<returnFromFunc1 | returnFromFunc2>> = {
      key1: this.Func1(data),
      key2: this.Func2(data)
}
for (const key of keys) {
    const serviceData = await serializationByService[key];
    console.log(serviceData)
    ... other actions 
}
```

But when i loop inside it, the log is executed before the return of the function called.
If i replace `await serializationByService[key];` by `await this.Func1(data);` then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If `this.Func1(data)` returns a promise, then building your data structure like this:

```
const serializationByService: Record<string, Promise<returnFromFunc1 | returnFromFunc2>> = {
      key1: this.Func1(data),
      key2: this.Func2(data)
}
```

will just create an object where each key contains a promise because that's what `this.Func1(data)` returns.  Then doing this:

```
await serializationByService[key];
```

will NOT wait for those promises that are in properties inside the object.  `await` just doesn't work that way.  So, if you want the actual promise resolved value in your object, then that's why you have to put the `await` inside the object definition to get the resolved value as you've discovered:

```
const serializationByService: Record<string, Promise<returnFromFunc1 | returnFromFunc2>> = {
      key1: await this.Func1(data),
      key2: await this.Func2(data)
}
```